# How can I connect Cloud66 with Jenkins to run a cucumber test after a deploy?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, cloud66

I have a rails server app running in [Cloud66](http://www.cloud66.com) and I want my [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org) to start running a test every time there is a deploy in Cloud66.

Is it possible to do this? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out the solution!

So:

1. We have to go to the Jenkins job and activate, under **Build Triggers** the option **Trigger Builds Remotely**. Then we have to choose a token.
2. We have to to **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure Global Security** and add **Read rights** to the **Anonymous user**.
3. Then, on the Rails project, create the file ./.cloud66/deploy_hooks.yml with this code:

-

```
staging:
   last_thing:
     command: curl $JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/build?token=$TOKEN_DEFINED_EARLIER
     target: rails
     execute: true
```

And that's it! Then you'll have an test execution triggered on deploy!